# Repeated measures ANOVAs

Tags: repeated-measures, spss

Hi I have a question regarding the within subjects contrasts in repeated measures ANOVA provided by SPSS. If we were to use a RM ANOVA and follow this up with post hoc tests, in a graph indicating where these differences lie, do we use the results from the RM ANOVA to show the differences or use results from the post hoc t-tests conducted later to show where these differences lie?

Answer (score 2):

The ANOVA tells you that there is an effect, i.e. at least one of the means is different.  You are not allowed to do any post-hoc t-tests with out doing the ANOVA.  In any write up, you must first say the results of the ANOVA.

If the ANOVA is significant you can do further tests. If the ANOVA is non-significant, then you shouldn't do any tests.

Regarding the post-hoc tests, the most popular is the Tukey-HSD comparison test.  The whole point of doing the ANOVA to begin with is that ordinary paired t-tests are inappropriate, because they do not incorporate the pooled variance estimate implied by the RM ANOVA's null hypothesis (whereas the post hoc estimates use the residual individual variance for the test statistics).

Comment: Thank you for editing my answer so nicely.  Most grateful.

Comment: We are all learning here. :) Except me... I might be *unlearning*. :D